# Mathlandia Cake Cutting (very short riddle)

Tags: lateral-thinking

In Mathlandia, everything is divided perfectly. A cake has just been cut into 9 pieces, so every piece has 0.111 of the cake, right? Jeff the cake cutter confirms this is so. But $1 - 9 \cdot 0.111 = 0.001;$ what happened to the 0.001?

Comment: What's wrong with the riddle that's making so many people vote against it?

Comment: (re your comment) I can't explain why others downvoted this, only why I did: (a) You say "so every piece has 0.111 of the cake, right?" meaning that that's an assumption, but the assumption is wrong. If you cut something evenly into nine pieces, you get (ideally) 1/9, not 0.111. Not only is it wrong, but that wrongness is precisely the assumption that the rest of your question rests on -- if you would've gotten this part right, then you'd have had no question. (b, and less importantly) Your question has a careless typo. "1−9⋅0.999=0.001"; you meant "1−9⋅0.111=0.001".

Comment: The problem here is the setup, particularly the words "so" and "right?". Remove those, and the puzzle changes from irritating to at least halfway decent.

Comment: Personally I flagged this post because it is too broad: it is posed as a mathematical problem but it is very simple to came up with an answer similar to the intended one. There is no "clear" solution (not even a [lateral-thinking] one) that you can unarguably choose as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that miniscule amount remains stuck to the knife and/or serving plate?

Comment: Yes, you will find it on the knife.

Answer (score 2):

> Cutting a cake into 9 pieces yields pieces of 1/9 = 0.(1) of the cake; 0.001 was dropped due to rounding to the 3 digits.

Comment: Not so. Jeff is absolutely right, and each piece is $0.111$ of the whole cake.

Comment: @Displayname And you mean 0.111 exactly, not 0.[1] repeating?

Comment: @Deusovi Yes. $$  $$